# Initial voltages of capacitors using mesh currents analysis

Tags: capacitor, inductor, dual

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHiq1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The book I'm reading is noting that I should recognize the initial voltage across the \$C_1\$ capacitor is \$10 V\$ but I can't see why this is.  I see that by setting up the mesh equations for \$i_2\$ I would get:

\$-4\frac{di_1}{dt}\ + 4 \frac{di_2}{d_t} + \frac{1}{8} \int^t_{t_0}i_2dt' + 5i_2 + v_{C_1}(t_0) = 0\$

Could someone explain to my how \$10V\$ is derived?

Comment: It's just an assumption from an external source . Similar to analyzing a transformer that has Remanence and current cut off abruptly so the initial condition would be some previously applied magnetic field B(t) But not in the applied excitation given.. same here.... the purpose is to demonstrate an exponential offset decay and an exponential resonant decay (2nd and 1st order terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "why".  To start analyzing the circuit at any point in time, anything with "stored" state has to be known.  In this case these are the current thru the inductor, the voltage across the capacitor, and the phase of the sine voltage source.

10 V is something they simply picked.  It's a starting state they want you to analyze the circuit from.